# session having different session ids on different pages of single domain, non secure pages!

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I'm pulling my hair out over this one. I have tried to make a simple script to store sessions so when a user closes there browser, they can come back later and their shopping basket will still be in tact. This all seemed to be going fine until i noticed that on some items the basket was containing same items as the previous. After some checks I noticed the session id was different on these odd pages! Here's my code which sits at the top of my framework.

```
<?php

session_start();
function sessions(){
    if( ! isset( $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] ) ) {
        setcookie( "PHPSESSID", session_id(), strtotime('+ 30 days') );
    }else{
        $con = Database::getInstance();
        if( session_id() != $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] ) {
            $re = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` WHERE session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "'" );
            if( $re->num_rows != 0 ) {
                $ar = $re->fetch_assoc();
                $id = $ar['id'];
                $_SESSION['basket'] = unserialize( stripslashes( $ar['basket'] ) );
                $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET session_id = '" . session_id() . "' WHERE id = '$id' " );
            }
            unset($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']);
            setcookie( "PHPSESSID", session_id(), strtotime('+ 30 days') );
            header('Location: ' . get_base_url() );
        }else{
            $re = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` WHERE session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "'" );
            if( $re->num_rows != 0 ) {
                $ar = $re->fetch_assoc();
                $id = $ar['id'];
                if( ! empty( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) {
                    $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "', data = '" . addslashes( serialize( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) . "' WHERE id = '$id'" );
                }else{
                    $con->query( "DELETE FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` WHERE id = '$id'" );  
                }
            }else{
                if( ! empty( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) {
                    $con->query( "INSERT INTO `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` ( `session_id`, `stamp`, `data`) VALUES ( '" . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . "', NOW(), '" . addslashes( serialize( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) . "' )" );  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo 'cookie: ' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . ' : session(): ' . session_id();
}

?>
```

any help on this matter is much appreciated.

** EDIT **

i've tried to make it more simpler but still same problem

```
<?php

function sessions(){
    $con = Database::getInstance();
    if( session_id() == '' ) {
        if( isset( $_COOKIE['session_id'] ) ) {
            session_start();
            $re = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` WHERE session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . "'" );
            if( $re->num_rows != 0 ) {
                $ar = $re->fetch_assoc();
                $id = $ar['id'];
                if( session_id() != $_COOKIE['session_id'] ) {
                    $_COOKIE['session_id'] = session_id();
                    $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET session_id = '" . session_id() . "' WHERE id = '$id' " );
                    $_SESSION['basket'] = unserialize( stripslashes( $ar['data'] ) );
                }else{
                    if( isset( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) {
                        $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET data = '" . addslashes( serialize( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) . "' WHERE id = '$id' " );
                    }
                }   
            }else{
                $con->query( "INSERT INTO `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` ( `session_id`, `stamp`, `data`) VALUES ( '" . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . "', NOW(), '' )" );       
            }
        }else{
            session_start();
            setcookie( "session_id", session_id(), strtotime('+ 30 days') );
            $_COOKIE['session_id'] = session_id();
        }
    }else{
        die('session has previously been created'); 
    }
    echo 'cookie: ' . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . ' : session(): ' . session_id();
}

?>
```

Comment: Check the session cookie path where they are stored on the odd pages and on the normal pages

Comment: uri: http://localhost/eCom/clothes/mens/red_hat_thing cookie: d488a3qd58vpu2ic3putd7co06 : session(): d488a3qd58vpu2ic3putd7co06 path: c:/wamp/tmp

Comment: uri: http://localhost/eCom/clothes/small_men/hats/long_scarf_3 cookie: 1gq1q90sg4skjkorf1gg0urah1 : session(): 1gq1q90sg4skjkorf1gg0urah1 path: c:/wamp/tmp

Comment: I just deleted all sessions in c:/wamp/tmp, cleared my tabel and just browsed arround and yet again it created 2 different sessions

Comment: @Phil Jackson: When/where do you call the `sessions()` function? Also within each page right at the top when you include the file containing that function?

Comment: it's framework based so at the top of the index page.

Comment: To be honest: The problem is that you try to do what PHP’s session handler is already doing well: maintaining the session status. Why don’t you let PHP do it?

Comment: @Gumbo because it dies when a browser is closed...

Comment: @Phil Jackson: That’s the purpose of a session: it ends with the browser session.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

function sessions(){
    $con = Database::getInstance();
    if( session_id() == '' ) {
        session_start();
        if( isset( $_COOKIE['session_id'] ) ) {
            $re = $con->query( "SELECT * FROM `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` WHERE session_id = '" . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . "'" );
            display_error( $con );
            if( $re->num_rows != 0 ) {
                $ar = $re->fetch_assoc();
                $id = $ar['id'];
                if( session_id() != $_COOKIE['session_id'] ) {
                    setcookie( "session_id", '', strtotime('- 30 days'), '/', 'localhost' );
                    setcookie( "session_id", session_id(), strtotime('+ 30 days'), '/', 'localhost' );
                    $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET session_id = '" . session_id() . "' WHERE id = '$id' " );
                    display_error( $con );
                    $_SESSION['basket'] = unserialize( stripslashes( $ar['data'] ) );
                }else{
                    if( isset( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) {
                        $con->query("UPDATE `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` SET data = '" . addslashes( serialize( $_SESSION['basket'] ) ) . "' WHERE id = '$id' " );
                        display_error( $con );
                    }
                }   
            }else{
                $con->query( "INSERT INTO `" . TABLE_PREFIX . "_tbl_sessions` ( `session_id`, `stamp`, `data`) VALUES ( '" . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . "', NOW(), '' )" );       
                display_error( $con );
            }
        }else{
            setcookie( "session_id", session_id(), strtotime('+ 30 days'), '/', 'localhost' );
            $_COOKIE['session_id'] = session_id();
        }
    }else{
        die('session has previously been created'); 
    }
    echo 'cookie: ' . $_COOKIE['session_id'] . ' : session(): ' . session_id();
}

function display_error( $con ) {
    if( isset( $con->error ) && $con->error != '' ) {
        die( $con->error );
    }
}

?>
```

The Above works!
**$_COOKIES['foo'] = 'bar'** **does not** re-value the cookie in the browser only during the script.

The other problem was needing to set the **path** and **domain** of the cookie to stop multipul cookies being created. Works and runs smoothly!